# Getting problem while launching the Dataflow flex template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am getting the following problem while launching the dataflow flex template.

```
Error occurred in the launcher container: Template launch failed. See console logs
```

Everything was fine before Dec 13, 2020, 2:16:51 AM.

But after Dec 13, 2020, 2:16:51 AM every job is being failed.

I don't know what is wrong. I didn't update anything.

Is there anyone getting the same problem? Can anybody help me with this problem?

**Full Log Message:**

```
{
 insertId: "6dx1bnbsu"  
 labels: {
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id: "2020-12-15_21_10_01-10766180733224199975"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name: "tracking-data-pipeline"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/region: "us-central1"   
 }
 logName: "projects/project_id/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-12-16T05:22:01.470463269Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id: "2020-12-15_21_10_01-10766180733224199975"    
   job_name: "tracking-data-pipeline"    
   project_id: "project_id"    
   region: "us-central1"    
   step_id: ""    
  }
  type: "dataflow_step"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "Error occurred in the launcher container: Template launch failed. See console logs."  
 timestamp: "2020-12-16T05:22:00.427865178Z"  
}
```

Comment: There is simply not enough information to figure out what's going wrong here. As the message says, see console logs.

Comment: There is nothing on the console. The job is being dispatched automatically via Cloud Scheduler. And when I dispatch it from the terminal I don't get anything.

Comment: @Al-MamunSarkar I am also getting similar error; where does this console log exist? were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Console log means logs of the job. Just go to the details page of the job and find the logs link and just click on that.

Comment: under Job Logs panel, if you scroll up, there is a log message, which link to console logs. The console logs are stored in a GCS bucket

Comment: @TonyMurphy how do I know what GCS bucket the console logs are stored in?

Comment: @ShahNewazKhan there is a filter input on log levels, ensure you are viewing all log levels. First log line when no filtering on will specify GCS bucket + console_log path

Comment: Thanks @TonyMurphy, I found the gcs bucket to the console_log path from the first log line when filtering with `default` log level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing git inside the docker container. At the time of building the docker image, it was trying to pull some codes from a git repository, there wasn't git installed in the docker that's why it was throwing errors. After installing git is worked fine.

It can throw errors for a different reason. Just look at the logs you will be able to find out the reason.

Answer (score 3):

You should download the console logs and see what went wrong.

Here's how to do it. On the Job logs on Dataflow, look for a line that looks like this:

```
2021-11-17T20:41:41.068024028Z Console log from launcher will be available at gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-834770913771/staging/template_launches/2021-11-17_12_41_40-12088305213911934928/console_logs.
```

Then use `gsutil` to download that file:

```
gsutil cp gs://…etc…/console_logs .
```

Now look at the contents of `console_logs` and you should be able to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Adding apache-beam[gcp]==2.25.0 to the requirements.txt file solved it for me.