# Template launch failed while running a streaming dataflow job using flex-template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to automate provisioning of streaming job using cloud build, for the POC I tried https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/dataflow/flex-templates/streaming_beam

It worked as expected when I manually ran the commands.

When I add the commands in `cloudbuild.yaml` file the build gets created successfully but the dataflow job fails each time with the below error:

```
Error occurred in the launcher container: Template launch failed. See console logs
```

This is the only error log that I get, I tried to add extra permissions to Cloud Build service account but that didn't help either.

Since there's no other info mentioned in the log file I find it hard to debug it as well.

Comment: Have you added the `apache-beam` to your requirements file as an [older Stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306908/getting-problem-while-launching-the-dataflow-flex-template) suggests?

Comment: Yes, it's already present there, the same scripts when run manually work fine but I'm getting this issue when I try to automate it using cloud build

Comment: You can have a look at this [Git thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/4894#issuecomment-871635104) - it's still going and some comments give a hint about [what could be the reason for the error](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/4894#issuecomment-871635104). 

Try viewing the logs as described in that Git thread and share in your question to look at this closer.